# AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION doesn't work on all devices which are support VOICE_COMMUNICATION

Tags: android, audiorecord, echo-cancellation

I use **AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION** as source in my **AudioRecord** instance for all devices which support this. 
This works good on all my tablets except one. The *"Acer Iconia Tab 8"*.

AcousticEchoCanceler, AutomaticGainControl, NoiseSuppressor are available. 
The **Android Version is 4.4.2**

The receiving device only get audio data with a **buzzing**.
If i use **AudioSource.MIC** which is used on the fallback for devices which are not support **AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION** it works, but without the EchoCancelation which are needed and which should supported by this device.

```
final int bufSize = Math.max(1 * 2 * 8000, AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT));
AudioRecord rec;
try {
    final int src = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION;
    rec = new AudioRecord(src, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Log.d("AudioRecorder", "echo cancellation NOT enabled (old android version)");
    final int src = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
    rec = new AudioRecord(src, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufSize);
}
```

Anybody an idea about this strange behavior?

Comment: Can you please explain when you use VOICE_COMMUNICATION  exactly ? In which kind of app? Is it video/audio chat over the Internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem and solved it with an update of Android.